# Merging results are wrong

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas DataFrames:

```
df1:

    cid day         total_count
0   2   2017-06-01  1
1   2   2017-03-04  1
2   1   2017-04-07  1
3   4   2017-06-25  1
4   5   2017-03-18  2
4   3   2017-03-18  2
4   1   2017-03-18  2
4   5   2017-03-18  2

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["cid","pid","lat","lon"], data=[[1,1,41.485731,3.2409],     [2,2,41.49206,3.22573],[3,3,41.494026,3.22354],[4,4,41.495904,3.14504],[5,5,41.50271,3.12575]])
```

I want just to add two columns `lat` and `lon` to the table `df1` from table `df2`.

I tried to do it this way:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='cid', right_index=True, how='left', sort=False)
```

But I get a wrong result (`result.head()`):

```
    cid_x   day         total_count cid_y   pid     lat         lon
0   2       2017-06-01  1           1.0     1.0     41.475215   3.23462
1   2       2017-03-04  1           1.0     1.0     41.501326   3.41505
2   1       2017-04-07  1           2.0     2.0     41.484948   3.34780
3   4       2017-06-25  1           5.0     5.0     41.492983   3.43865
4   5       2017-03-18  1           3.0     3.0     41.502776   3.35977
```

First of all, I do not understand why I get two columns `cid_x` and `cid_y` instead of `cid`? Secondly, I misunderstand why the values of `cid_x` and `cid_y` are different for each row? Shouldn't the `merge` command merge rows from `df1` and `df2` based on `cid`?

I tried to show the issue based on dummy data.

Comment: see the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html
Maybe try `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='cid', how='left', sort=False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did your join is the reason. You're using the `cid` as the join key from your left df, while you're using the `index` from the right df. Hence, your pseudo join SQL would be something like: `on left.cid = right.index`

If you want to join on `cid` for both df's, then just use the simple `on` argument:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='cid', how='left')
```